# Rails 5 address form. Either fill out everything or default value if nothing is provided

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a model with address, city, state, zip. I would like the option for the user to not fill out anything OR make them fill out everything.

At the moment, a user can fill out whatever they want, only a city for example, and it saves.

I would like some validation that they need to fill out every column or nothing at all.

Is it possible to group validations together like that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Jquery Validation plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/),which is a good fit for this scenario.
its very light and easily configurable.

Add the js in the page and initialize the validator on your form by ..

```
 $("#form").validate({
  ///add rules for every input types and validations
  })
```

you can find basic examples here..

-- for [form validation](http://jsfiddle.net/amwmedia/sw87W/)

-- for [simple text box validaton](http://jsfiddle.net/klenwell/fz5Tx/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: It's good to add client side validations, but if someone replays the HTTP request using cURL or something, they can POST whatever they want, and it will still reach your database. If you want to be safe, you should also add server side validations. In your controller, you can add a little method like `params.map{ |k, v| v.present? }.all?` or something and render an `error` if not all values are present.

Comment: @Shiyason,its not possible to run curl from client.Moreover,you cannot reach db just by a http request as this will be CSRF breach.Its dependent more on the quality of code written by dev and how he has taken care of both client and server validations...

Comment: I am not implying the request will be sent from the client/browser. If someone inspects the network traffic using `chrome inspector`, `mitmproxy` or some other tool, they can simply modify the payload and resend the POST request. In this case, client side validations will be of no help. Is what I meant.. Also, I didn't mean to imply that HTTP requests would bypass the web app and reach the DB. I mean't without server side validations, the user's POST data would simply get saved to the DB.

Comment: Let the developer take care of it..and let us help him for the solution.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could define a condition to make the validation works, something like:

```
validates_presence_of :address, :city, :state, :zip, if: :any_field_filled?

def any_field_filled?
  attributes.any? { |_k, v| v.present? }
end
```

now, if you want to exclude some specific fields (like `id` or `created_at`/`updated_at`), you could try with:

```
FIELDS_TO_EXCLUDE = %w(id created_at updated_at).freeze

validates_presence_of :address, :city, :state, :zip, if: :any_field_filled?

def any_field_filled?
  attributes.any? do |k, v|
    !FIELDS_TO_EXCLUDE.include?(k) && v.present?
  end
end
```